# Hardware virtualization with vmware

Tags: virtualization, vmware-workstation

Is there a way to enable hardware virtualization for VMWare on Windows 7 if the CPU doesn't support this?

Comment: What makes you think that's possible?

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use hardware virtualization if the hardware can't do it.

Answer (score 1):

CPU support is what *hardware* virtualization **means** — it's [tautological](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/tautological).